# Limit results in sql query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following fields:

```
 id
 name
 date_created
 department
```

I want to get all the records sorted by `date_created`

But i want only 2 results from each department.

How can I do that?

Comment: please give us some data (more then 3 please) so we can get a closer look and write some Statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work -- you need to get your row number, grouped by department:

```
SELECT Id, 
  Name, 
  Date_Created, 
  Department
FROM (
    SELECT @curRow:=CASE WHEN @prevRow = Department THEN @curRow+1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
      Id, 
      Name, 
      Date_Created, 
      Department,
      @prevRow:=Department   clset
    FROM YourTable
      JOIN (SELECT @curRow:= 0) r
    ORDER BY Department, Date_Created DESC
  ) t
WHERE rn <= 2
```

And some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abb90/1).

Comment: Wow... Fast... Nice one! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tablename
group by department
order by date_created
limit 0, 2
```

Comment: I think they may want to group by department here

Comment: d'oh, the perils of writing a quick answer to show how the "limit" keyword is used! thanks for catching that.

Comment: I dont want to group data by department. I want all results but not more than 2 results from any department.

Comment: I've just flagged this as a dupe, if you have a look at the linked question in comments there are various solutions.